# server send emails using gmail smtp gets alerts

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

I did something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)  to make my web app sends mails through gmail's  SMTP. I tried locally and it worked. after I upload to the server (which is in another country) I get this error:

```
authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 534, response: 5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 5.7.9 {WEBLOGINREQUIRED} fl2sm1579003pab.23 - gsmtp)]
```

is there a way to ignore this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For anyone still interest the answer:

Google have to allow your app to use your own account, to allow this google provided an easy way, just go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha, then click `continue`, then with 10 min, use your application to try to send email again, and google will remember the application/service and allow your application to access your account as long as you don't change your password.

cheers

Comment: Great answer! saved a lot of time.

Comment: It could be only the temporary fix. You'd better to use another service to send your emails (more [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/48393)).

Comment: this works!, but can't find official documentation on this, anyone?

Comment: awesome... Thumbs up.